# Why is what I'm seeing in Arkham Knight different from what I see in online walk throughs?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I'm playing Arkham Knight on PC, purchased via Steam. There are some Riddler trophies that were so baffling that I got to a point where I felt something might be wrong. So, I looked up some walk throughs, and I discovered that what I'm seeing doesn't match what other people show.

For example, I'm in Panessa Studios, Studio C, and there is a Riddler trophy right in front of a sort of slot machine thing, with hearts, clubs, diamonds, and spades on it.

Here is what it looks like to me:

[image: My Batman]

But, when I look online, here is what the walk throughs show:

[image: Other batman]

In the image I took from a walk through, there are four screens with red symbols that are accessible with the hacking device, and critical to solving the riddle.

But in mine, those screens aren't there, and without them, I don't see any way of solving the riddle.

This is only one of many differences in trophy locations inside Panessa Studios. In any case, why does this look different for me? Is this a PC bug? Is there something I need to do to activate the screens? Do I need to have gone further in the game (it says I am 87% compete in the main mission).

Comment: Could it be that the trophy is locked due to story constraints, such as hallucination, for instance?

Comment: Is the walkthrough also on PC?

Comment: very misleading title. would be worth reconsidering it to garner the attention you seek

Comment: @Timelord64, I have no problem changing the title, but I'm not sure what is misleading about it. What you recommend?

Comment: @Nolonar, that is part of what I am asking. If that is the case, then hopefully someone can tell me.

Comment: @Dpeif, it's not entirely clear, but I can't find any online resource that explains if there is any difference between the PC and console versions that would account for what I am seeing. I'm not seeing any sites that say "this is a walkthrough for the PC" versus "this is a walkthrough for consoles".

Comment: Doesn't this game have anti-piracy measures which 'change' things so some things aren't possible - I haven't played the game so no idea if this is one of those changes btw.

Comment: @djsmiley2k, that may or may not be true, but since I purchased my game on Steam, then if it applies to me, it is because a bug is incorrectly applying the measures.

Comment: Then it's not that and nothing to worry about there.

Comment: I have no sources for this, so unless someone can confirm I'll leave this as a comment - When the game was released for PC it was adapted from the console version (and very poorly so... as you may well know). However, I believe it was re-built, which may lead to the dirrences you are seeing. Additionally, depending on the date/platform the guide was made, may also contribute to this.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that the screens needed to access the trophy referenced in the question become available after you progress further in the game's main mission. It doesn't seem to be tied to any particular event, like getting any upgrade or anything. Just somewhere after finishing about 70% or so of the main mission, these trophies just became available.

It's a little confusing, because if, like me, you like to get information from as many Riddler informants as possible and get all the Riddler trophies before finishing the main mission, you'll see trophy locations added to the map not only for trophies you can't solve, but for trophies you can't even see yet.

There's one trophy that was added to my map that is in front of a statue with a circular track around it, in the area that connects the three studios in Panessa Studios. However, when I first went to the location, the trophy wasn't there, and I thought it must be under the floor or hidden somehow, so I thought part of the riddle was to search for it. But, it just isn't there until some later point in the game when it's released.

So, the lesson learned is that if a riddle seems impossible to find or solve, then progress further in the game and check again.

Comment: Such a valuable lesson. I spent so long looking for some trophies that then just turned up in plain site later. I'd almost recommend leaving any exhaustive attempt at trophy hunting (ie anything that involves more than a five second look at a location) til you are basically nearly done with the game.